# How to get a final model from a full model (GLM)?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I have a problem with the selection of the correct covariates in a GLM.
My dataset derives from a field ornithological study. I want to see if my variable Y = parent feeding rate (number of visits to the nest per hour) depends on other variables that should influence the feeding rate according to the literature.

This is the formula and the output:

```
Call:
glm(formula = logFfeed ~ CHICKS_TOT + LAYING + F_BODY.INDEX + 
    F_AGE + PROP_EPY + EPP + logMfeed, data = mydata.complete)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.59961  -0.19183  -0.09137   0.25045   0.59695  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   2.724678   1.200184   2.270   0.0301 *
CHICKS_TOT    0.071065   0.071041   1.000   0.3247  
LAYING       -0.014373   0.017318  -0.830   0.4127  
F_BODY.INDEX  0.004387   0.027844   0.158   0.8758  
F_AGE         0.041543   0.037262   1.115   0.2732  
PROP_EPY     -0.570717   0.275443  -2.072   0.0464 *
EPP           0.191846   0.194663   0.986   0.3318  
logMfeed      0.012745   0.170511   0.075   0.9409  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1199304)

    Null deviance: 4.9966  on 39  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 3.8378  on 32  degrees of freedom
  (9 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 37.756

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Now from this full model I would like to arrive at a final model with only the highly significant explanatory variables. To do that I used the stepwise algorithm.

```
step(FIT1.F, direction = "backward")
Start:  AIC=37.76
logFfeed ~ CHICKS_TOT + LAYING + F_BODY.INDEX + F_AGE + PROP_EPY + 
    EPP + logMfeed

               Df Deviance    AIC
- logMfeed      1   3.8384 35.763
- F_BODY.INDEX  1   3.8407 35.787
- LAYING        1   3.9204 36.607
- EPP           1   3.9543 36.952
- CHICKS_TOT    1   3.9578 36.987
- F_AGE         1   3.9868 37.280
<none>              3.8378 37.756
- PROP_EPY      1   4.3527 40.791
Error in step(FIT1.F, direction = "backward") : 
  the number of lines in use has changed: do I eliminate missing values?
```

It gives me this error. I tried to eliminate all missing values from the dataset, but by doing so my dataset is significantly reduced (from 49 lines to 14 rows).  Is there any other strategy to select the covariates that better explain the model?

Comment: You mention that you're running a GLM, but by default the GLM function uses the Gaussian distribution. This means that you're running a standard OLS regression (i.e., the same model you get by using the lm() function in R) since you're also not changing the link function. Is this what you intended to do? Or, is there a specific generalized linear model that you want to use?

Comment: Also, there are a lot of ways to consider down-sizing your model. For example, you could run several versions of the model using a various combinations of predictors and then use likelihood-ratio tests (i.e., the anova() function in R) to compare the models. It's all going to boil down to what you goal is here. Are you intended to select a model without making any assumptions about what predictors should be retained? Are you trying to identify relevant predictors based on a prior theory? Are you trying to make a highly accurate prediction of the outcome variable?

Comment: The distribution of my variable Y is normal, so I chose family = gaussian. I ran the model with three different link functions (identity, log, inverse) and the lowest AIC corresponded to the link = identity. Since "family = gaussian(link=identity)" is given by default I left only the formula and dataset. Did I do wrong?

Comment: Regarding the goal of my analysis, I would say that it comes close to your second question. "Are you trying to identify relevant predictors based on a prior theory? ". I have done a bibliographic research on what are the bird's trait that can influence its parental care. All the covariates I have included in the model are those that showed a significat assosiation with feeding rate in previous study. I want to see if my data also show these relations. In general if and which  variables of my dataset influence the feeding rate.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you did per se. glm() with family = gaussian(link = "identity") is the same result as you get with the lm() function. I just wanted to make sure that you didn't need to specify another distribution since that's usually why someone would used glm() vs. lm().

Now, if all you want to do is see whether variables were significant based on theory, then you have your final model. From what is reported here, you are able to answer your research question. There's no need to do a stepwise algorithm since it doesn't matter which are selected, just which are significant.